# A Milk solution of 60 litres contains..

Tags: average

A Milk solution of 60 litres contains 80% milk. How many litres of another milk solution containing 90% milk should be added to make an 84% milk solution? [Ans: 40 lit]

I tried: $\dfrac {80}{100}\times \dfrac {M}{60}$

$\dfrac {M}{25}$

calculation of second sentence:

$\dfrac {M}{60}\times \dfrac {84}{100}$

$\dfrac {21 M}{1500}$

calculation of first part in second sentence:

$\dfrac {M}{60}\times \dfrac {90}{100}$

Final equation: $\dfrac {M}{60}\times \dfrac {90}{100} = \dfrac {M}{25} - \dfrac {21 M}{1500}$

I gone too far, is my approach right or wrong? if wrong, tell me the correct procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work with the percentages of volume.  Note that "of" usually means multiplication.  The initial percentage-volume plus the added percentage-volume will equal the resultant percentage-volume:
$$60*\frac{80}{100}+n*\frac{90}{100}=(60+n)*\frac{84}{100}$$
You should be able to take it from there.

Comment: Please tell me why is my approach wrong?

Comment: To start with , it appears you were dividing the percentage by the volume, instead of multiplying.  Also, you inserted the variable $M$ where no unknowns are present.  My first term is for the first sentence.